# Insert json file to mysql with flask

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to insert the data from a json file called output.json and i have this code:
I'm getting this error:

MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting

In mysql i insert like insert into t1 values ({JSONFILE})

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
 
app = Flask(__name__)
 
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = '*****'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = '*****'
 
mysql = MySQL(app)


@app.route("/sendf",methods=['POST'])
def sendfilet():
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    file = open('output.json', 'r')
    file_content = file.read()
    file.close()
    sql = "INSERT INTO t1 (tablename) VALUES (%s)"
    val = (json.dumps(file_content))
    cursor.execute(sql, val)
    db.commit()
    db.close()
    return 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,port=5050)
```

my json is like this:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"60f458945d77cb5ec7872b61"},"insertionDate":{"$date":"2021-07-18T16:36:36.193Z"},"sessionData":{"time":["1364","1374","1384"],"yaw":["0.15","0.3","0.45"],"pitch":["0.36","0.76","1.08"],"roll":["-0.13","-0.25","-0.35"],"ax":["-0.42","-0.41","-0.41"],"ay":["-0.15","-0.13","-0.1"],"az":["0.9","0.91","1"],"gx":["0","0","0"],"gy":["-0.01","0","-0.01"],"gz":["0.02","0.02","0.02"],"mx":["0.26","0.26","0.26"],"my":["0.01","0.01","0.01"],"mz":["-0.04","-0.04","-0.07"]},"metaData":{"userId":123456,"gender":"M","ageGroup":"SENIOR","weightKg":70,"heightCm":175,"poolSizeM":50}}
```

Comment: json_to_sql = json.dumps(json_you_want_to_save)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I put this instead insert into?

Comment: You need to insert to table a new row with columm value, see example https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: mycursor = mydb.cursor()
json_to_save = .... #from file
sql = "INSERT INTO t1 (json_column) VALUES (%s)"
val = (json.dumps(json_to_save))
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
mydb.commit()

Make sure that you have table t1 and collum with name: "json_column"

Comment: i've tried but i'm getting the same error:MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to store your JSON data into MySQL in python, you can to create a `MySQLUtil` so that you can insert your JSON data in MySQL.

You can do `mysql = MySQLUtil()`

After this, you need to make a connection to the database and then store the JSON data into a variable, and simply use `MySQLstrong text.execSql()` to insert the data.

```
(your json variable name) = pymysql.escape_string(// your json data)
Mysql = "insert data (index name) value"('" + json_data + "') "
mysql.execSql(sql)
```

you can read more here [Python JSON encoder and decoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: ```def sendfilet():
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    file = open('output.json', 'r')
    file_content = file.read()
    file.close()
    sql = "INSERT INTO t1 (tablename) VALUES (%s)"
    val = (json.dumps(file_content))
    cursor.execute(sql, val)
    db.commit()
    db.close()
    return 200 ``` i change to his but i'm getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

For test Python code, first you try it:

```
from pathlib import Path
from . import mysql # because I use blueprint, so i import it from __init__.py, you can pass it.
@app.route("/sendf", methods=['GET'])
def sendfilet():
    try:

        print("File      Path:", Path(__file__).absolute())
        print("Directory Path:", Path().absolute())  # Directory of current working directory, not
        #file_path = str(Path().absolute())+'/output.json'
        parent_path = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
        file_path = f"{str(parent_path)}/output.json"
        print(file_path, file_path)
        file = open(file_path, 'r')
        file_content = file.read()
        file.close()
        #print(file_content)
        try:
            cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
                cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_json")
                property_count = cursor.fetchone()[0] # to get current ID, 
                sql = """INSERT INTO test_json (id, json_content) 
                                VALUES (%s, %s)"""
                #sql = "INSERT INTO test (json_content) VALUES (%s)"

                row_id = property_count+1 # make new id
                val = (row_id, file_content)
                cursor.execute(sql, val)
                mysql.connection.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    return "OK", 200
```

if you dont have the column ID with primary key in table, error will come.
My test table with name "test_json"
[image]

I think you should use SQLAlchemy, it is better than flask_mysqldb, easy to autoincrement id.

```
id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I create the table with two columns, id primary key and json_content datatype json but id works but json not. It appears empty

Comment: def sendfilet():
    connection = mysql.connect() 
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    file = open('output.json', 'r')
    file_content = file.read()    
    file.close()
    cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_json")
    property_count = cursor.fetchone()[0] # to get current ID, 
    sql = "INSERT INTO test_json (id, json_content) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    row_id = property_count+1 # make new id
    tests= (json.dumps(file_content))
    print(tests)
    val = (row_id, tests)
    cursor.execute(sql, val)
    connection.commit()
    return "test",200

Comment: I test my code, it run well